# Have we had any posts on MMSE that were generated by AI or written with the help of AI?

Tags: discussion, posts-written-with-help-from-ai

The Quantum Computing Stack Exchange [has had several cases](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/584/2293) of posts that were deleted due to looking like they were written by ChatGPT or written with ChatGPT's help.

Has MMSE experienced this, whether ChatGPT was involved or any other artificially intelligent software?

Comment: Why is that a problem, though ?

Comment: @HarshdeepChhabra why is what a problem?

Comment: If a user has written a post (or even a accurate answer) using ChatGPT why would that be against the website policy?

Comment: @HarshdeepChhabra where did anyone mention anything about policy here?

Comment: This question just got two AI-generated answers from spam accounts: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/12273/5

Answer (score 1):

## 24 January 2024: First confirmed example

This question: [How do I draw perovskite structure with own without CIF file?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/12273/5) had two AI-generated answers on 24 January 2024, within 2 hours of each other. It's hard to see now, since the user profiles have been destroyed, but they were accounts that were advertising (spamming) some company that had nothing to do with matter modeling, which made it unlikely that the authors of those answers wrote the answers themselves. One question also opened with almost a repeat of the question's title, which seems like something that an AI-based bot would do, and Camps confirmed to me that one of the answers used the same wording as what he got from asking ChatGPT the same question. The same two accounts came back and tried to answer a different question slightly later (I can find that one too by looking at my flag history, if I flagged them).